Issue with a tooltip following my cursor in an svg
I created a graph of the S&P 500 in a React App using d3 and svgs. I wanted to style the graph by adding alternate shading on the graph to further visually highlight the start and end of each year. I created user interactivity by creating mouseMove and mouseLeave functionality that provides the graph value when the user hovers over different points in the graph. Almost creating a crosshair look to show where you are on the graph. The only problem is that when I add the alternate shading, it interferes with the crosshairs rendering on my mouse position, and snaps back to the origin point of my graph.The crosshairs work fine when the cursor is not in the shaded areas, but snaps to the (0,0) point in the graph when the cursor is hovering over a shaded portion of the graph. I suspect the issue has to do with the transform translate values of the alternate shaded rectangles, but I tried a few ways to render these rectangles (using different transform coordinates to start the drawing of the rectangles) and the crosshairs still snap to the origin when I hover over a shaded area. It might have to do with how I created the functions for the mouseMove and mouseLeave functions, but I'm running out of ideas. How can I still make the crosshairs work when hovering over the shaded areas of the graph?
Here is my code:
// You need to figure out why there is a big black box in front of your graph when you tried to add a tooltip

import * as d3 from "d3";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
//import styles from './AreaGraph.module.css';
import useMeasure from "react-use-measure";
import { format, startOfYear, startOfMonth, startOfQuarter, endOfYear, endOfMonth, endOfQuarter, eachYearOfInterval, eachMonthOfInterval, eachQuarterOfInterval, isSameYear, isSameMonth, isSameQuarter } from "date-fns";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const AreaGraph2 = ({ height, width, dates, values, data }) => {
    // const tooltipRef = useRef(null);
    //let [reference, bounds] = useMeasure();
    const tooltipRef = useRef();
    const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 15, left: 35 };
    const graphWidth = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const graphHeight = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    let previousData = [];

    const [xPos, setXPos] = useState(0);
    const [yPos, setYPos] = useState(0);
    const [prevD, setPrevD] = useState([]);
    const [tooltipVisible, setTooltipVisible] = useState(false);
    const [tooltipPosition, setTooltipPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });


    // const width= graphWidth + margin.left + margin.right;
    // const height= graphHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom;

    // console.log(data);
    // const data2 = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => [key, value]);
    // console.log(`data2: ${data2}`);

    // Check if data is valid and not empty
    if (!Array.isArray(data) || data.length === 0) {
        return <div>No data available</div>;
    }

    // Check if data points are valid numbers
    const isValidData = data.every(([x, y]) => Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === '[object Date]' && typeof y === 'number');
    if (!isValidData) {
        return <div>Data contains invalid values</div>;
    }

    // // Check if data points are valid numbers
    // const isValidData = data.every(([x, y]) => typeof x === 'number'Object.prototype.toString.call(date) && typeof y === 'number');
    // if (!isValidData) {
    //     return <div>Data contains invalid values</div>;
    // }

    // console.log(typeof(data[0][1]));
    // console.log(data[0][0]);
    // console.log(data[0][0] instanceof Date);
    // console.log(data[data.length - 1][0])
    // console.log(data[data.length - 1][0] instanceof Date)
    // const data3 = data2.map(([_, value]) => [value[0], value[1]]);
    // console.log(`data3: ${data3}`);

    let startYear = startOfYear(data.at(0)[0]); // Takes first datetime data point in the ascending-order dataset and sets the datetime data point to the start of that year
    let endYear = endOfYear(data.at(-1)[0]); //  Takes the last datetime data point in the ascending-order dataset and sets the datetime data point to the end of that year
    let years = eachYearOfInterval({ start: startYear, end: endYear}); // Creates an array of one datetime object from each year that starts on 01 Jan 00:00:00
    // console.log(years);
    let startMonth = startOfMonth(data.at(0)[0]); // Takes first datetime data point in the ascending-order dataset and sets the datetime data point to the start of that year
    let endMonth = endOfMonth(data.at(-1)[0]); //  Takes the last datetime data point in the ascending-order dataset and sets the datetime data point to the end of that year
    let months = eachMonthOfInterval({ start: startMonth, end: endMonth}); // Creates an array of one datetime object from each year that starts on 01 Jan 00:00:00
    // console.log(months);

    let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([startYear, endYear]) // Passed in an array of the minimum and maximum dates in the passed in data. Note that the d3.domain() method requires an Array of 2 values - .domain([start, end])
            //data[0][0], data[data.length - 1][0]
            //d3.extent(data.map((d) => d[0]))
            .range([margin.left, width-margin.right]);
            
    let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data.map((d) => d[1])))
            .range([height-margin.bottom, margin.top]);

    let line = d3.line()
            .x((d) => xScale(d[0])) //Returns the x value of each point in the data, and wraps it in the xScale to scale the data across the graph. In this dataset, the first value in each array of value pairs (aka the 'x' in the [x, y] array) is the datetime object.
            .y((d)=> yScale(d[1])); //Returns the y value of each point in the data, and wraps it in the yScale to scale the data uo and down the graph. In this dataset, the second value in each array of value pairs (aka the 'y' in the [x, y] array) is the S&P500 points value in a floating point number form.

    let result = line(data); // Takes the data passed into the component via a prop, and passes it through the d3.line() function to create the drawing line for the d attribute in the <path> element that will be embedded in the <svg> element.

    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
        const { clientX, clientY } = event;
        const svgRect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const mouseX = clientX - svgRect.left;
        const mouseY = clientY - svgRect.top - margin.top;
        
        setXPos(mouseX);
        setYPos(mouseY);

        setTooltipPosition({ x: mouseX, y: mouseY});

        // Find the nearest data point based on mouse position
        let nearestDataPoint = null;
        let minDistance = Infinity;
        data.forEach((d) => {
            const dist = Math.abs(xScale(d[0]) - mouseX);
            if (dist < minDistance) {
                minDistance = dist;
                nearestDataPoint = d;
            }
        });

        if (nearestDataPoint) {
            // Snap the crosshairs to the nearest data point
            setXPos(xScale(nearestDataPoint[0]));
            setYPos(yScale(nearestDataPoint[1]));
            setPrevD(nearestDataPoint); // Optional: Save the nearest data point for reference
        }

        // Show tooltip
        setTooltipVisible(true);
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        // Hide tooltip
        setTooltipVisible(false);
    };

    // const mouseover = (event, d) => {
    //     setXPos(d[0])
    //     setYPos(d[1])
    //     //event.target.style['stroke-opacity'] = '1';
    //     event.target.style['stroke-opacity'] = '1';
    //     // console.log(format(xPos, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), yPos)
    //     };
  
    //   const mouseout = (event) => {
    //     //event.target.style['stroke-opacity'] = '0';
    //     event.target.style['stroke-opacity'] = '0';
    //   };

    //data.map(d => console.log(years.findIndex(y => isSameYear(y, d[0])) % 2 === 1 ? "" : format(d[0], "yyyy")))

    return (
        <>
            <svg
                className=""
                viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height + 15}`}
                onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
                onMouseLeave = {handleMouseLeave}
            >

                {/* X-Axis minor axis and tick labels */}
                {years.map((year) => ( // Takes the years variable which creates an array of each of the years on the graph, and performs a map array method for each year
                    <g                                              // Create a <g> element to group the entire X-Axis shading drawing.
                        transform = {`translate(${xScale(year)},${height-margin.bottom})`} // Alter the frame of reference to start each drawing at the beginning of the year, and end each drawing at the end of each year. The height is set to 0 so the drawing of each rectangle starts at the top of the SVG element, since SVG coordinates (0,0) typically start the top left
                        className="fill-current" 
                        key={year}
                    >
                        <line
                            //key={`line-${index}`}
                            y1={0}
                            y2={margin.top-height + 10}
                            stroke='#718096'
                            strokeWidth={0.5}
                            strokeDasharray="2,4"
                        />
                        {!(year.getYear() === data.at(0)[0].getYear() || year.getYear() === data.at(-1)[0].getYear() || year.getYear().toString().endsWith('0')) && (
                        <text
                           //key={`text-${index}`}
                        //    alignmentBaseline="middle"
                            x={((xScale(endOfYear(year)) - xScale(year))/2)}
                            y={10}
                            textAnchor='middle'
                            style={{ fontSize: '10px', fill: '#718096' }}
                        >
                            {format(year, "yy")}
                        </text>
                        )}
                    </ g>
                ))}

                {/* X-Axis Shading */}
                {years.map((year, i) => (
                    <g
                        transform={`translate(${xScale(year)}, ${height-margin.bottom})`}
                        className="fill-current"
                        key={year}
                    >
                        {i % 2 === 1 && (
                            <path
                                d={`M 0 0 L ${xScale(endOfYear(year)) - xScale(year)} 0 L ${xScale(endOfYear(year)) - xScale(year)} ${margin.top - height + 10} L 0 ${margin.top - height + 10} Z`}
                                fill="#F0F4FF"
                            />
                        )}
                    </g>
                ))}

                {/* {years.map((year, i) => (
                    <g
                        transform={`translate(${xScale(year)}, ${height-margin.bottom})`}
                        className="fill-current"
                        key={year}
                    >
                        {i % 2 === 1 && (
                            <rect
                                width={xScale(endOfYear(year)) - xScale(year)}
                                height={margin.top-height}
                                fill="#F0F4FF"
                            />
                        )}
                    </g>
                ))} */}

                {/* {years.map((year, i) => (
                    <g                                              // Create a <g> element to group the entire X-Axis shading drawing.
                    transform = {`translate(${xScale(year)},${14})`} // Alter the frame of reference to start each drawing at the beginning of the year, and end each drawing at the end of each year. The height is set to 0 so the drawing of each rectangle starts at the top of the SVG element, since SVG coordinates (0,0) typically start the top left
                    className="fill-current" 
                    key={year}
                    >
                        {i % 2  === 1 && (
                            <rect
                                width={xScale(endOfYear(year)) - xScale(year)}
                                height={height-margin.bottom-14}
                                //className='text-green-800'
                                fill='#F0F4FF'
                                // This color is good for the rectangles: #F0F4FF
                                // fillOpacity='8%'
                            />
                        )}
                    </ g>

                ))} */}
                {/* Y-axis */}
                {yScale.ticks(5).map((points) => (
                    <g
                        transform = {`translate(0,${yScale(points)})`} 
                        className="text-gray-400" 
                        key={points}
                    >
                        <line
                            //key={`line-${index}`}
                            x1={margin.left}
                            x2={width - margin.right}
                            stroke='#718096'
                            strokeWidth={0.5}
                            strokeDasharray="2,4"
                        />
                        <text
                           //key={`text-${index}`}
                           alignmentBaseline="middle"
                            x={0}
                            style={{ fontSize: '10px', fill: '#718096' }}
                        >
                            {points}
                        </text>
                    </ g>
                ))}

                {/* X-axis */}
                {xScale.ticks(4).concat(startOfYear(data.at(0)[0])).concat(startOfYear(data.at(-1)[0])).map((date) => (
                    <g
                        transform = {`translate(${xScale(date)},${height - 5})`} 
                        className="text-gray-400" 
                        key={date}
                    >
                        <line
                            //key={`line-${index}`}
                            y1={height - margin.bottom}
                            y2={margin.top}
                            stroke='black'
                            strokeWidth={1}
                            strokeDasharray="2,4"
                        />
                        <text
                           //key={`text-${index}`}
                        //    alignmentBaseline="middle"
                            x={-6}
                            y={1}
                            transform={`rotate(50 ${0},${0})`}
                            style={{ fontSize: '12px', fill: '#718096' }}
                        >
                            {/* xScale(endOfYear(year)) - xScale(year) */}
                            {format(date, "yyyy")}
                        </text>
                    </ g>
                ))}
                {/* Line */}
                <motion.path
                    initial = {{ pathLength: 0 }}
                    animate = {{ pathLength: 1 }}
                    transition = {{ duration: 6, delay: 1.5, type: "spring" }}
                    d={result}
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                />
                {/* X-Axis Hidden Rectangles*/}
                {/* I did the X-Axis Shading last and just brought it up to the top so that it draws onto the svg first, so the line draws over the shading. SVG elements draw in the order they are shown, so these shaded boxes are drawn at the bottom, before the line or dotted axes. */}
                {/* {data.map((d, i) => ( // Takes the years variable which creates an array of each of the years on the graph, and performs a map array method for each year
                    <g                                              // Create a <g> element to group the entire X-Axis shading drawing.
                        transform = {`translate(${xScale(d[0])},0)`} // Alter the frame of reference to start each drawing at the beginning of the year, and end each drawing at the end of each year. The height is set to 0 so the drawing of each rectangle starts at the top of the SVG element, since SVG coordinates (0,0) typically start the top left
                        className="fill-current" 
                        key={d} 
                    >
                        {
                            <line
                                y1={height -15}
                                y2={0}
                                className='highlightRectX'
                                //className='text-green-800'
                                stroke='darkblue'
                                stroke-opacity='0'
                                onMouseOver={(e) => mouseover(e, d)}
                                onMouseOut={(e) => mouseout(e)}
                                // This color is good for the rectangles: #F0F4FF
                                // fillOpacity='8%'
                            />
                        }
                    </ g>
                ))} */}
                {/* Crosshairs */}
                <g id="crosshairs" style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
                    <line x1={margin.left} x2={width - margin.right} y1={yPos} y2={yPos} stroke="gray" strokeWidth="1" strokeDasharray="4" />
                    <line x1={xPos} x2={xPos} y1={margin.top} y2={height - margin.bottom} stroke="gray" strokeWidth="1" strokeDasharray="4" />
                </g>

                {/* {data.map((d, i) => ( // Takes the years variable which creates an array of each of the years on the graph, and performs a map array method for each year
                    <>
                        <g                                              // Create a <g> element to group the entire X-Axis shading drawing.
                            transform = {`translate(0,${yScale(d[1])})`} // Alter the frame of reference to start each drawing at the beginning of the year, and end each drawing at the end of each year. The height is set to 0 so the drawing of each rectangle starts at the top of the SVG element, since SVG coordinates (0,0) typically start the top left
                            className="fill-current" 
                            key={d} 
                        >
                            {
                                <line
                                    x1={width}
                                    x2={0}
                                    className='highlightRectX'
                                    //className='text-green-800'
                                    stroke='darkblue'
                                    stroke-opacity='0'
                                    onMouseOver={(e) => mouseover(e, d)}
                                    onMouseOut={(e) => mouseout(e)}
                                    // This color is good for the rectangles: #F0F4FF
                                    // fillOpacity='8%'
                                />
                            }
                        </ g>
                        <g                                              // Create a <g> element to group the entire X-Axis shading drawing.
                            transform = {`translate(${xScale(d[0])},0)`} // Alter the frame of reference to start each drawing at the beginning of the year, and end each drawing at the end of each year. The height is set to 0 so the drawing of each rectangle starts at the top of the SVG element, since SVG coordinates (0,0) typically start the top left
                            className="fill-current" 
                            key={d} 
                        >
                            {
                                <line
                                    y1={height -15}
                                    y2={0}
                                    className='highlightRectX'
                                    //className='text-green-800'
                                    stroke='darkblue'
                                    stroke-opacity='0'
                                    onMouseOver={(e) => mouseover(e, d)}
                                    onMouseOut={(e) => mouseout(e)}
                                    // This color is good for the rectangles: #F0F4FF
                                    // fillOpacity='8%'
                                />
                            }
                        </ g>
                    </>
                ))} */}
                {/* Circles */}
                {data.map((d, i) => (
                    <motion.circle
                        initial = {{ cy: height - margin.bottom, scale: 0 }}
                        animate = {{ cy: yScale(d[1]), scale: 1 }}
                        transition = {{ type: "spring", duration: 1, delay: 0.006 * i }}
                        key={d[0]}
                        r="1"
                        cx={xScale(d[0])}
                        cy={yScale(d[1])}
                        fill="currentColor"
                        stroke={years.findIndex(y => isSameYear(y, d[0])) %2 == 1 ? '#F0F4FF' : 'white'}
                        // strokeOpacity={years.findIndex(y => isSameYear(y, d[0])) %2 == 1 ? '100%' : '100%'}
                        strokeWidth={0.5}
                    />
                ))}
      {/* .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout); */}
            </svg>
            {tooltipVisible && (
                <div
                    className="tooltip"
                    style={{ top: yPos + margin.top, left: xPos + margin.left }}
                >
                    Date: {format(xScale.invert(xPos), 'MM/dd/yyyy')}, Value: {yScale.invert(yPos)}
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};


export default AreaGraph2;

Here is the link to the repository:
https://github.com/drcasas2/sp500dataviz.git
And here is a link to the live site if you want to see what the problem is. Hover over any of the blue shaded sections and the crosshair snaps back to (0, 0):
https://drcasas2.github.io/sp500dataviz/
If you need any more context, please let me know, since I'm EAGER to solve this problem.
Thanks!
Under {/* X-Axis Shading */}, I started with rectangle svg elements, and tried altering the origin from which the rectangles are rendered by trying transform = {translate(${xScale(date)},${0}) with a positive height value or transform = {translate(${xScale(date)},${height - 5}) with a negative height value (but the rectangles wouldn't render with a negative height value, so I switched to using a path to define the rectangles. None of these options have worked for me so far.
